# How to center all div elements inside one flex item with flexbox model css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new in frontend development, I am studying now HTML/CSS flexbox model.

So I am making one project.

I have a main-contant div as a flex container. Inside this flex container I have 3 boxes. Each of these boxes is also a flex container with 3 div containers as a column.

My task is to center all elements inside each of these 3 boxes. When I put a text-align property to the each of these 3 containers, only first 2 containers inside of the div are centered, but the last one with buttons doesn't.

I don't know how to fix it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kJLj.png)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* margin: 0; */
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* background-color: rgb(223, 255, 133); */
}

.main-content {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    /* background-color: blueviolet; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.main-content__feature {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* background-color:burlywood; */
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-content__feature-dark {
    background-color: darkblue;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(81, 172, 247), rgb(126, 248, 143));
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;

}

h2 {
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 156);
}

.main-content__font-p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 190);
}

.main-content__font-p-price {
    color:rgb(80, 185, 150);
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight:800;
}

.main-content__font-p-italic {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 190);
}

.main-content__button-1 {
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(61, 201, 189);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #777777;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-content__button-2 {
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* background-color: rgb(61, 201, 189); */
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(61, 201, 189);
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(61, 201, 189);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px; 
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #777777;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="main-content">
          <div class="main-content__feature">
              <div class="main-content__description">
                  <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">SMD</h2>
                  <h2>Basic</h2>
                  <p class="main-content__font-p">6 months program</p>
                  <p class="main-content__font-p-price">$595</p>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content__servises main-content__font-p-italic">
                  <p>2 physician visits</p>
                  <p>12 coaching segments</p>
                  <p>24 programm worksheet</p>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content__buttons">
                  <div class="main-content__button-1">BUY NOW</div>
                  <div class="main-content__button-2">Programm details</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-content__feature main-content__feature-dark">
            <div class="main-content__description">
                <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">SMD</h2>
                <h2>Basic</h2>
                <p>6 months programm</p>
                <p>$595</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__servises">
                <p>2 physician visits</p>
                <p>12 coaching segments</p>
                <p>24 programm worksheet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__buttons">
                <div class="main-content__button-1">Buy NOW</div>
                <div class="main-content__button-2">Programm details</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-content__feature">
            <div class="main-content__description">
                <h2>SMD</h2>
                <h2>Basic</h2>
                <p>6 months programm</p>
                <p>$595</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__servises">
                <p>2 physician visits</p>
                <p>12 coaching segments</p>
                <p>24 programm worksheet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__buttons">
                <div class="main-content__button-1">Buy NOW</div>
                <div class="main-content__button-2">Programm details</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: You have not centered anything in `main-content__buttons`

Comment: Add to `.main-content__button-1` and to `.main-content__button-2` `margin: 0 auto 10px auto;`

Comment: main-content__buttons is inside of div class="main-content__feature. And I added a text-align property to this class. Everything inside this class was centered (everything is two classes), but div class main-content__buttons didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* margin: 0; */
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* background-color: rgb(223, 255, 133); */
}

.main-content {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    /* background-color: blueviolet; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.main-content__feature {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* background-color:burlywood; */
    flex-grow: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-content__feature-dark {
    background-color: darkblue;
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(81, 172, 247), rgb(126, 248, 143));
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;

}

h2 {
    /* text-transform: uppercase; */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 156);
}

.main-content__font-p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color:rgb(0, 0, 190);
}

.main-content__font-p-price {
    color:rgb(80, 185, 150);
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight:800;
}

.main-content__font-p-italic {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 190);
}

.main-content__button-1 {
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(61, 201, 189);
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #777777;
    margin:auto;
}
.main-content__button-2 {
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* background-color: rgb(61, 201, 189); */
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(61, 201, 189);
    padding-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(61, 201, 189);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px; 
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #777777;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="main-content">
          <div class="main-content__feature">
              <div class="main-content__description">
                  <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">SMD</h2>
                  <h2>Basic</h2>
                  <p class="main-content__font-p">6 months program</p>
                  <p class="main-content__font-p-price">$595</p>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content__servises main-content__font-p-italic">
                  <p>2 physician visits</p>
                  <p>12 coaching segments</p>
                  <p>24 programm worksheet</p>
              </div>
              <div class="main-content__buttons">
                  <div class="main-content__button-1">BUY NOW</div>
                  <div class="main-content__button-2">Programm details</div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-content__feature main-content__feature-dark">
            <div class="main-content__description">
                <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">SMD</h2>
                <h2>Basic</h2>
                <p>6 months programm</p>
                <p>$595</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__servises">
                <p>2 physician visits</p>
                <p>12 coaching segments</p>
                <p>24 programm worksheet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__buttons">
                <div class="main-content__button-1">Buy NOW</div>
                <div class="main-content__button-2">Programm details</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-content__feature">
            <div class="main-content__description">
                <h2>SMD</h2>
                <h2>Basic</h2>
                <p>6 months programm</p>
                <p>$595</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__servises">
                <p>2 physician visits</p>
                <p>12 coaching segments</p>
                <p>24 programm worksheet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content__buttons">
                <div class="main-content__button-1">Buy NOW</div>
                <div class="main-content__button-2">Programm details</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I used the float:; command.